# install directus 7 with docker

Tags: windows, docker, directus

I am installing directus 7 with docker on a windows machine, and I have trouble starting directus. When I make the command: docker restart "Container ID".

I tried this command:
docker restart "Container ID", the images start and stop a few seconds later.
Just one image remains booted.

result:

-Containers:
96a185f982e8        directus/core:7-apache
5da264ce559b        directus/core:7-apache
af673c439a57        directus/core:7-apache
24c1912c5536        directus/base:7-api-apache
607b8725e3e2        directus/base:7-app-node

-Containers status:
 Exited (1) 50 seconds ago
 Exited (1) 31 seconds ago
 Exited (1) 17 seconds ago
 Exited (1) 5 seconds ago
 Up 19 hours

[result after docker restart containers](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7Ra8o.png)

Comment: try to check with `docker logs <container_id>` what's the problem

Comment: --On the container that does not start I have this result: 
$ docker logs 96a185f982e8
standard_init_linux.go:211: exec user process caused "no such file or directory"
standard_init_linux.go:211: exec user process caused "no such file or directory"
--And the container that starts normally gives this:
$ docker logs 607b8725e3e2
listening at http://0.0.0.0:80

Comment: maybe you should add also how your started the varius containers

Comment: I start my container with the command:
$ docker start 24c1912c5536
24c1912c5536

Comment: ok, I change the question... How did you create the containers?

Comment: I install directus, and then I execute: ./bin/build --type all --version 7.0.0

Comment: that just builds the image. did you try running it with composer from examples folder?